# How do I check if Java Access Bridge is enabled? (PowerShell)

Tags: java, powershell, java-access-bridge

I have created a utility that checks for various perquisites/requirements needed for a machine setup. But, I am running into an issue where I want to check if JAB (Java Access Bridge) is enabled or disabled through PowerShell either through a location path of a file or registry entry would be great.

There is this website documentation that references how to use the jabswitch.exe to enable or disable JAB via command line, but as mentioned above, I am wanting to check if enabled/disabled.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/access/enable_and_test.htm#JSACC-GUID-7890D37B-16F2-48EC-B45F-2A6CF0613EE5

Is this possible to do (Without taking a screenshot in the Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center)?

Comment: I went a double checked the two you mentioned from the linked documentation and here is what I retrieved.. "**To use the jaccessinspector tool, launch the jaccessinspector Windows application after launching a Java application**". So `jaccessinspector` is a no go and "**To use jaccesswalker, launch the jaccesswalker Windows application after launching a Java application**" `jaccesswalker` is also a no go. Unless I am missing something... ? I am just want to add a check through PowerShell for JAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code of [`jabswitch`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/jdk.accessibility/windows/native/jabswitch/jabswitch.cpp) you find that it does two things:

- it writes a file `%USERPROFILE%\.accessability.properties` which contains two lines starting with `#` (if disabled) or not (if enabled)
- it updates at the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility` the value `Configuration` which either contains `oracle_javaaccessbridge` (if enabled) or doesn't contain it (if disabled)

Comment: The registry entry is the easiest to grab for my PowerShell check needs and seems to work flawlessly. I greatly appreciate the response and hope all others reading benefit from this information. I marked as "Accepted Answer".